# Mongodb list collection without showing views

Tags: mongodb

To get collection names without showing view names in mongodb.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(collection) {
indexes = db[collection].getIndexes();
print("Indexes for " + collection + ":");
printjson(indexes);
```

});

```
2019-05-06T13:57:17.166-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listIndexes failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Namespace DB.yy_kikttypes is a view, not a collection",
    "code" : 166,
    "codeName" : "CommandNotSupportedOnView"
```

} :

the view name is causing trouble & coming out of loop. So is there a way to show only collection rather than views or anyway to continue loop without coming out in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [db.getCollectionInfos()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/#db-getcollectioninfos) filtering only on collections. For example:

```
db.getCollectionInfos({ type: "collection" }).forEach( ... )
```

Comment: **For readers : Be careful** 

Running `db.getCollectionInfos({ type: "collection" })` will also return `system.views` collection. Do verify the output before iterating on the results

Comment: I was about to use this snippet to drop collections and narrowly escaped an apocalypse

Answer (score 1):

That helped. I came up with this solution:

```
db.getCollectionInfos({ type: "collection" }).forEach(function(v1) {  printjson(v1.name);  v2=v1.name;  indexes = db[v2].getIndexes();  print("Indexes for " + v2 + ":"); printjson(indexes);  } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as Adam Harrion's answer but without "system.views":

```
db.getCollectionInfos({ type: "collection", name:{$ne:"system.views"} }).forEach(function(v1) {  printjson(v1.name);  v2=v1.name;  indexes = db[v2].getIndexes();  print("Indexes for " + v2 + ":"); printjson(indexes);  } );
```